Setting a scale for y when there are two y axis
I am currently graphing river discharge behind water quality measures such as salinty and pH.
This is the graphs of salinity and pH by themselves:


(The NA in the site is a bit inevitable I think as I had to match it to discharge data by hour so there are a lot of NAs, when I removed it it also removed a lot of the discharge data.)
Here is the code for salinity:
Sal<-ggplot(CHEM_RESULTS, aes(x= `Timestamp`, y=`Salinity`, 
                             col=Site))+
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=34), lty=2, col="red")+
geom_line(size=1, alpha=0.9, linetype=1, na.rm = TRUE)+
geom_point(na.rm = TRUE)+
scale_color_manual(values=c("orchid4","darkorange","royalblue4", "steelblue1"))
Sal

The red line is the government guideline for water quality.
Now when I add the discharge graph the scale for the y axis with Salinty and pH goes to 0 so they are plotted really small.


I tried ylim() however I got this message:
Scale for y is already present.
Adding another scale for y, which will replace the existing scale.

Code for second salinity graph:
Sal+ scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./1))
scale=1
Sal+
ylim(20,35)+
geom_line(aes(y = cumec*scale), color="powderblue", linewidth=1, alpha=0.4, 
          linetype=1)+
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./1, name="Discharge (cumec)"))+
ggtitle("Salinity Saturation in Gold Coast Broadwater 
(Yugambeh Country) Against Nerang River Discharge") +
xlab("Date")+
theme(text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", size= 14))


Secondary axes in ggplot2 are just a "decoration," so you have to use algebra to convert your secondary axis data into the primary axis, and then apply the opposite transformation to the secondary axis itself.

@JonSpring thank you - would I not run into the same problem again though with discharge being from 0-20 as primary axis and sec axis being different scale.

Use of coord_cartesian is (almost) always better than ylim. It probably won’t make any difference here, but it’s a good habit to learn, IMHO. You can avoid the NAs in your legend by deleting the data argument from your ggplot call and replacing it with (suitably filtered) additions to the individual geom_xxxx calls.
